# Not able to connect ethernet network to my ASUS laptop

Tags: 14.04, asus

I have an issue connecting my ASUS laptop (ubuntu 14.04) to wired internet connection that follows DHCP protocol. All i can say is when i connect it will pulsate for few seconds and then disconnects. I tried and found some answers on similar issue but couldn't help myself. Any help in this regard would be thankful.

Not to forget, same network works fine on other devices (desktop with also ubuntu) and from the service centre of ASUS i came to know that socket of my laptop works fine.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, try with another cable. Be sure that eth-wire has 4-pair inside ( totally 8 wires).

Then, if the problem persist, may be is a problem about autonegotiation.  Try to set the negotiation as manual at your Network Manager. Set as 100Mb/s

If the problem persist, we need more information:

- open a terminal and look at `mii-tool ethX` where X is your
  interface number. Here you can see in what state is your interface.
  Can you post us this state during first 10 seconds and later?
- Other important information is in `ethtool`util. Can you install it
  via wifi `sudo apt-get install ethtool`

  Run `ethtool ethX` where X is you interface number and post us your
  information.
- Model of your ASUS laptop and model of your router/switx where ASUS is connected

Comment: Mr. Gilito, Thanks for your time. As per your reply i checked my ethernet wire and found only four wires (orange, green, white with a orange line and another white with green line).Also i would like to make you remember from my above question that the ethernet wire works fine with my desktop and more over i don't have a wifi router to get connected to the network because of which i not able to post the further information you required. Model: Asus X54H (laptop)

Comment: It's possible that on wire with only 2 pairs doesn't work fine with one PC and with another yes. Can you confirm that in a 4 pair wire isn't runing too?